# how to override the already existing workspaces in rtc using command scm or lscm

Tags: batch-file, rational-team-concert, ibm-rational

I have the requirement as i need to connect to the rtc and automatically checkout the files from the stream to the repository workspace.
I am writing the following commands in the bat file.

```
lscm login -r https://rtc.usaa.com/ccm -u uname -P password -n nickname -c
scm create workspace (workspacename) -r nickname -s (streamname)
lscm load workspace name -r nickname -d directorypath(c:codebase/rtc)
lscm logout -r nickname
```

while i am executing the above batch file for the first time it is creating the workspace and loading the project into the workspace path.
while i am executing the above batch file for the second time again it is creating the duplicate workspace with the same name and getting exception while loading.
I want to override the already existing workspace every time while loading but I didn't find a command for that.
can you please provide me any other way of doing it or any command that solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to delete existing local workspace sandbox before loading the new one. In my setup, we execute the following steps:
1. Delete local sandbox (if it makes sense delete existing repository workspace too)
2. Create new repository workspace
3. Load the new repository workspace to local sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Either create a uniquely named workspace (perhaps by sticking a time stamp into the name?) and then delete it when you're done, or use the workspace's UUID from the creation step.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting and again writing the files into workspace, you can try accept incoming changes before load and then using "--force" attribute you can overwrite only the changes made files.

Accept using - SCM accept --flow-components -r <> -u <> -p <> --target

Use force at the end of the load command which you using.

this should work fine.